# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str #num is set as a int

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

```
31, in <module>
    check_store[(abcd[int(num)])] = (com_que_store[int(num)])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

It looks like the error is when I am trying to access the index of one of my lists.
I've looked everywhere and I can't find/make a solution. Can anyone help?

Here is the code I am running to get the above error:

```
import random
from random import randint 
from time import sleep as s

run = True
num = 0
diff = int(input('1-3'))

que_1 = 'wright 1'
que_2 = 'wrong 2'
que_3 = 'wrong 3'
que_4 = 'wrong 4'

que_store = [que_2, que_3, que_4]
com_que_store = [que_1]
check_store = []
abcd = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in range(diff):
        r = randint(0,(2 - num))
        print(que_store[r])
        com_que_store.append(que_store[r])
        que_store.pop(r)
        num = num + 1

print(com_que_store)
random.shuffle(com_que_store)
print('\n\n\n')
print(com_que_store)
num = 0
num = int(num)

for value in com_que_store:
        print(abcd[num], com_que_store[num])
        check_store[(abcd[int(num)])] = (com_que_store[int(num)])
        num = num + 1

print(com_que_store)
```

Comment: Please format your code. This is hard to read. Highlight it and press ctrl+k.

Comment: Well, `check_store` is a list, and you are indexing it using elements of `abcd` which are `str`'s. Also, you should avoid the overuse of parentheses.

Comment: thanks, how can I change it too integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do in your code. But from what I can tell this will do what you want it to do. Please comment if you were intending for it to do something else.

I cleaned up a lot of the formating. And changed the last `for` loop to loop to all of the values in com_que_store to check_store. I am sure this is not the full intention of your code, but now it might be easier for you to addapt it to for your use.

```
from random import randint, shuffle

run = True
num = 0
diff = int(input('Pick a number from 1-3: '))

if not diff <= 3 and diff >= 1:
    print('Make sure your number is from 1 to 3')
    raise TypeError

que_1 = 'wright 1'
que_2 = 'wrong 2'
que_3 = 'wrong 3'
que_4 = 'wrong 4'

que_store = [que_2, que_3, que_4]
com_que_store = [que_1]
check_store = []
abcd = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in range(diff):
    r = randint(0, (2 - num))
    print(que_store[r])
    com_que_store.append(que_store[r])
    que_store.pop(r)
    num = num + 1

print(com_que_store)
shuffle(com_que_store)
print('\n\n\n')
print(com_que_store)

for value in com_que_store:
    print value
    check_store.append(value)
    num = num + 1
```

Comment: thankyou, I have fixed my code thanks to you. its part of a large program this is just a part my code. my issue was a silly mistake and I setting check_score to a list and I was trying to make a dictionary I just used the wrong parentheses by accident. thank you for helping me and I realise my code can be much more efficient and better. thank you -sam.